# Why does lchown() always fail on group in root process via xinetd?

Tags: c++, ssh, usergroups, xinetd, lchown

I have a C++ application that summons a server on another machine via the `xinetd` service on Linux Centos5 64 bit. The summoned process is invoked as root, but I think it may be a root that does not have full capabilities because of what I observe in my application.

In my application, running as root via inetd invocation, I create a new file and link (each initially user root and group root) and then call `lchown()` successfully on the owner, but it always fails on the group with EPERMS, `Operation not permitted`. Combining the user and group into a single invocation of `lchown()` fails similarly.

The code in question in my application is like this:

```
::lchown("pathnameToFile", uid_t(500), static_cast<unsigned>(-1)); // This line works
::lchown("pathnameToFile", static_cast<unsigned>(-1), gid_t(500)); // This line fails
::lchown("LinkToPathname", uid_t(500), static_cast<unsigned>(-1)); // This line works
::lchown("LinkToPathname", static_cast<unsigned>(-1), gid_t(500)); // This line fails
```

The newly created files live in as NFS mounted directory with permissions like this after my code runs:

```
drwxrwxr-x   2 me me   4096 Jun 22 17:33 .
drwxrwxrwx   2 me me   4096 Jun 22 17:33 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1 me root   33 Jun 22 17:33 pathnameToFile
lrwxrwxrwx   1 me root    8 Jun 22 17:33 LinkToPathname -> pathnameToFile
```

The gid 500 is the primary group for 'me', the other group being 'wheel'.

```
> groups
me wheel
```

From the shell prompt, I can do `chgrp` logged in as `root` to group `me` with no issues.

Why does lchown() behave differently when my application is invoked via inetd? Note that the same application invoked as root via `ssh` properly sets the group owner of the file.  Why is root via ssh different than root via xinetd?

Comment: Are these files on an NFS-mounted filesystem or other network filesystem by any chance?

Comment: @Kenster Yes, it is NFS mounted, but given that SSH works, should that be an issue?

Comment: I was thinking that [root squashing](http://linux.die.net/man/5/exports) on the NFS server might be involved, but on rereading the question, probably not.